# Play Framework 2.3.8 ManyToMany relationships and YAML

Tags: jpa, playframework, many-to-many, yaml, snakeyaml

thanks in advance for reading this. I'm now trying to solve my problem for over a week and can't find the solution.

I'm trying to populate my ManyToMany relationships via a YAML file but for some reason it doesn't work.

Her are my Classes:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {

@Id
public Integer id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JsonManagedReference
public Set<Language> languages = new TreeSet<Language>();


@Entity
public class Language extends Model {

@Id
public Integer id;
public String  name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "languages", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JsonBackReference
public Set<Company> companies = new TreeSet<Company>();
```

YAML:

```
 - &language1 !!models.Language
    id: 1
    name: English


- &language2 !!models.Language
    id: 2
    name: Mandarin


- &language3 !!models.Language
    id: 3
    name: Cantonese


- &company1 !!models.Company
    id: 1
    languages:
      ? *language1
      ? *language2
      ? *language3

- &company2 !!models.Company
    id: 2
    languages:
      ? *language1
      ? *language3

- &company3 !!models.Company
    id: 3
    languages:
      ? *language1
      ? *language3
```

Global:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    // Check if the database is empty
    if (User.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
        Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("initial-data1.yml"));
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to to get my Company Objects in Json, the languages Set is empty.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would split the problem into two smaller ones. Can you view the database with some UI tool to check whether it was populated or not? Then could you please add the code with `gets Company Objects in Json` - maybe there is a problem with fetching languages there.

Comment: @cosmolev Just checked the database the table Company_Language is not getting populated. Heres the get method of the Company Class: `public static Result getCompanies() {
        List<Company> companies = new Model.Finder(String.class, Company.class).all();
        return ok(toJson(companies));
    }`